# Translate a generic DAG structure to an AWS step-function via TypeScript/AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-step-functions, directed-acyclic-graphs, aws-cdk-typescript

I have the following requirement:

Assume a generic DAG structure -- an array of nodes and an array of edges.

A single node has a couple of fields that aren't really relevant besides the "id" field; each edge has a "source id" and a "target id" field.

Given this structure, I want to generate an AWS step-function definition via TypeScript AWS CDK.

Each node in AWS terms needs to translate to a lambda invocation, where the node properties are the input for the invocation.

It's important that parallelism is dictated by the structure, i.e. if node "C" has dependencies of nodes "A" and "B", "C" will wait until both "A" and "B" are finished.